# Check if File exists in S3 using Powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am writing a script that does a Copy-S3Object from S3 using Powershell, however, I need to check the bucket before for a .ready file.  The bucket has a folder /test/*.ready.  I know how to check my local for a file, but can't figure out how to check the S3:

```
    Initialize-AWSDefaultConfiguration -AccessKey $AKey -SecretKey $SKey -Region $region

Set-Location $source
$files = Get-ChildItem 'test/*.ready' | Select-Object -Property Name
try {
   if(Test-S3Bucket -BucketName $bucket) {
      foreach($file in $files) {
         if(!(Get-S3Object -BucketName $bucket -Key $file.Name)) { ## verify if exist
            Copy-S3Object -BucketName $bucket -Key $s3File -Region $region -AccessKey $Akey -SecretKey $SKey -LocalFolder $localpath
         } 
      }
   } Else {
      Write-Host "The bucket $bucket does not exist."
   }
} catch {
   Write-Host "Error uploading file $file"
}
```

Comment: Note that you're potentially doing something here that may set you up for surprises.  If you check for this file before it exists, you may subsequently find that it still appears **not** to be there for a short time after it is created.  Similarly, it may appear to exist for a short time after it is deleted.  An object present/absent test is not a suitable locking/semaphore mechanism because of S3's eventual consistency model, which also has implications for objects that are requested before they exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check like this as well (remove the forward slash after ready in the below snippet   if you want to test file):

```
if(Get-S3Object -BucketName abhibucketsss | where{$_.Key -like "test/*.ready/"}){
"Folder found"
}
else{
"Folder Not found"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use "[Head Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html)" API to see if the S3 file/Object is created. Here is PowerShell equivalent for HeadObject.

[Get-S3ObjectMetadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/Index.html)

> The HEAD operation retrieves metadata from an object without returning
>   the object itself. This operation is useful if you're only interested
>   in an object's metadata. To use HEAD, you must have READ access to the
>   object.

**Example**

```
try {$metadata = Get-S3ObjectMetadata -BucketName bucket-name -Key someFile.txt; "Found"} catch { "Not Found" }
```

Answer (score 5):

### ***Update:** I have fully developed a script/module you can read about it [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/one-way-sync-aws-s3-bucket-using-powershell-loveparteek-tiwana) and download the code [here](https://github.com/ltiwana/Sync-Files-To-AWS-S3-Bucket).

I was in the same situation, so I started working on a PowerShell script that syncs data and not overwrites it.

Write-s3Object CMDlet will overwrite by default, and I checked there is no option to specify not to overwrite existing files.

This is how I check if the Local folder exists on S3:

```
if ((Get-S3Object -BucketName $BucketName -KeyPrefix $Destination -MaxKey 2).count -lt "2") {
```

This  is how I check if the file exists and if the S3 file is the same size as the local file.

```
$fFile = Get-ChildItem -Force -File -Path "LocalFileName"


$S3file = Get-S3Object -BucketName "S3BucketName" -Key "S3FilePath"
$s3obj = ($S3file.key -split "/")[-1]

if ($fFile.name -eq $s3obj -and $S3file.size -ge $fFile.Length) {
    WriteWarning "File exists: $s3obj"

}
```

Here is the full script.

```
Function Sync-ToS3Bucket {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
    [string]$BucketName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2)]
    [string]$LocalFolderPath,
    [string]$S3DestinationFolder,
    [string]$S3ProfileName,
    [string]$AccessKey,
    [string]$SecretKey,
    [switch]$ShowProgress

)

Function WriteInfo ($msg) {
    Write-Host "[$(get-date)]:: $msg"
}

Function WriteAction ($msg) {
    Write-Host "[$(get-date)]:: $msg" -ForegroundColor Cyan
}

Function WriteWarning ($msg) {
    Write-Host "[$(get-date)]:: $msg" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}

Function WriteError ($msg) {
    Write-Host "[$(get-date)]:: $msg" -ForegroundColor Red
}

Function WriteLabel ($msg) {
    "`n`n`n"
    Write-Host ("*" * ("[$(get-date)]:: $msg").Length)
    $msg
    Write-Host( "*" * ("[$(get-date)]:: $msg").Length)
}

function Calculate-TransferSpeed ($size, $eTime) {
    writeInfo "Total Data: $size bytes, Total Time: $eTime seconds"
    if ($size -ge "1000000") {

        WriteInfo ("Upload speed         : " + [math]::round($($size / 1MB)/$eTime, 2) + " MB/Sec")
    }
    Elseif ($size -ge "1000" -and $size -lt "1000000" ) {

        WriteInfo ("Upload speed         : " + [math]::round($($size / 1kb)/$eTime,2)+ " KB/Sec")
    }
    Else {
        if ($size -ne $null -and $size) {
            WriteInfo ("Upload speed         : " + [math]::round($ssize/$eTime,2) + " Bytes/Sec")
        }
        else {
            WriteInfo ("Upload speed         : 0 Bytes/Sec")

        }
    }
}

function Get-ItemSize ($size, $msg) {
    if ($size -ge "1000000000") {
        WriteInfo "Upload $msg Size   : $([math]::round($($size /1gb),2)) GB"

    }
    Elseif ($size -ge "1000000" -and $size -lt "1000000000" ) {
        WriteInfo "Upload $msg Size   : $([math]::round($($size / 1MB),2)) MB"

    }
    Elseif ($size -ge "1000" -and $size -lt "1000000" )  {
        WriteInfo "Upload $msg Size   : $([math]::round($($size / 1kb),2)) KB"

    }
    Else {
        if ($size -ne $null -and $size) {
            WriteInfo "Upload $msg Size   : $([string]$size) Bytes"
        }

        else {
            WriteInfo "Upload $msg Size   : 0 Bytes"

        }
    }
}


clear
"`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n"
$OstartTime = get-date


if ($LocalFolderPath.Substring($LocalFolderPath.Length -1) -eq '\') {
    #$LocalFolderPath =  $LocalFolderPath + '\'
    $LocalFolderPath =  $Localfolderpath.Substring(0,$Localfolderpath.Length -1)
}
if ($S3DestinationFolder.Substring($S3DestinationFolder.Length -1) -eq '\') {
    #$LocalFolderPath =  $LocalFolderPath + '\'
    $S3DestinationFolder =  $S3DestinationFolder.Substring(0,$S3DestinationFolder.Length -1)
}
set-location $LocalFolderPath
$LocalFolderPath = $PWD.Path

Start-Transcript "AWS-S3Upload.log" -Append
"`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n"
WriteLabel "Script start time: $OstartTime"

WriteAction "Getting sub directories"
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $LocalFolderPath -Directory -Recurse -Force | select FullName

WriteAction "Getting list of all files"
$allFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $LocalFolderPath -File -Recurse -Force | select FullName

WriteAction "Getting folder count"
$FoldersCount = $Folders.count

WriteAction "Getting file count"
$allFilesCount = $allFiles.count

$i = 0

foreach ($Folder in $Folders.fullname) {


    $UploadFolder = $Folder.Substring($LocalFolderPath.length)
    $Source  = $Folder

    $Destination = $S3DestinationFolder + $UploadFolder



    if ($ShowProgress) {
        $i++
        $Percent = [math]::Round($($($i/$FoldersCount*100)))
        Write-Progress -Activity "Processing folder: $i out of $FoldersCount" -Status "Overall Upload Progress: $Percent`%     ||     Current Upload Folder Name: $UploadFolder" -PercentComplete $Percent
    }
    "`n`n"
    "_" * $("[$(get-date)]:: Local Folder Name    : $UploadFolder".Length)
    WriteInfo "Local Folder Name    : $UploadFolder"
    WriteInfo "S3 Folder path       : $Destination"

    WriteAction "Getting folder size"
    $Files = Get-ChildItem -Force -File -Path $Source | Measure-Object -sum Length

    Get-ItemSize $Files.sum "Folder"

    if ((Get-S3Object -BucketName $BucketName -KeyPrefix $Destination -MaxKey 2).count -lt "2") {

        WriteAction "Folder does not exist"
        WriteAction "Uploading all files"


        WriteInfo ("Upload File Count    : " + $files.count)

        $startTime = get-date
        WriteInfo "Upload Start Time    : $startTime"
        Write-S3Object -BucketName $BucketName -KeyPrefix $Destination -Folder $Source -Verbose -ConcurrentServiceRequest 100

        $stopTime = get-date
        WriteInfo "Upload Finished Time : $stopTime"

        $elapsedTime = $stopTime - $StartTime
        WriteInfo ("Time Elapsed         : " + $elapsedTime.days + " Days, " + $elapsedTime.hours + " Hours, "  + $elapsedTime.minutes + " Minutes, " + $elapsedTime.seconds+ " Seconds")

        Calculate-TransferSpeed $files.Sum $elapsedTime.TotalSeconds

        #sleep 10
    }
    else {
        WriteAction "Getting list of local files in local folder to transfer"
        $fFiles = Get-ChildItem -Force -File -Path $Source

        WriteAction "Counting files"
        $fFilescount = $ffiles.count
        WriteInfo "Upload File Count    : $fFilescount"
        $j=0
        foreach ($fFile in $fFiles) {

            if ($ShowProgress) {
                $j++
                $fPercent = [math]::Round($($($j/$fFilescount*100)))
                Write-Progress -Activity "Processing File: $j out of $fFilescount" -Id 1 -Status "Current Progress: $fPercent`%           ||     Processing File: $ffile" -PercentComplete $fPercent
            }
            #WriteAction "Getting S3 bucket objects"

            $S3file = Get-S3Object -BucketName $BucketName -Key "$Destination\$ffile"
            $s3obj = $S3file.key -replace "/","\"

            if ("$S3DestinationFolder$UploadFolder\$ffile" -eq $s3obj -and $S3file.size -ge $ffile.Length) {
                WriteWarning "File exists: $s3obj"

            }
            else {

                WriteAction "Uploading file       : $ffile"

                Get-ItemSize $fFile.Length "File"
                $startTime = get-date
                WriteInfo   "Upload Start Time    : $startTime"

                Write-S3Object -BucketName $BucketName -File $fFile.fullname -Key "$Destination\$fFile" -ConcurrentServiceRequest 100 -Verbose

                $stopTime = get-date
                WriteInfo "Upload Finished Time : $stopTime"

                $elapsedTime = $stopTime - $StartTime

                WriteInfo ("Time Elapsed         : " + $elapsedTime.days + " Days, " + $elapsedTime.hours + " Hours, "  + $elapsedTime.minutes + " Minutes, " + $elapsedTime.seconds+ " Seconds")
                Calculate-TransferSpeed $fFile.Length $elapsedTime.TotalSeconds
                break

            }

        }

    }

}

$OstopTime = get-date
"Script Finished Time : $OstopTime"

$elapsedTime = $OstopTime - $OStartTime

"Time Elapsed         : " + $elapsedTime.days + " Days, " + $elapsedTime.hours + " Hours, "  + $elapsedTime.minutes + " Minutes, " + $elapsedTime.seconds+ " Seconds"

stop-transcript
}
```

Run the script in your AWS Powershell instance and it will create a cmdlet or function.

You can use it like this:

**Sync-ToS3Bucket -BucketName** *YouS3BucketName* **-LocalFolderPath** *"C:\AmazonDrive\"* **-S3DestinationFolder** *YourDestinationS3folderName* -**ShowProgress:$true**

- make sure  to use relative path
- Make sure you have initiated your defaultAWSconfiguration by running `Initialize-AWSDefaultConfiguration`
- By default, the script will not show progress which is better for performance, but you can turn it on by using switch `-showProgress:$true`
- The script will create a folder structure as well
- You can use it to sync a local folder to S3. If the folder doesn't exist on S3, then the script will upload the whole folder. If the folder exists, then the script will go through each file on a local folder and make sure it exists on S3.

I am still working on improving the script and will publish it on my GitHub profile. Let me know if you have any feedback.

Some screenshot:
[image]

[image]